# 'PylintSensor' skipped because there is no related rule activated in the quality profile

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, pylint

I would like to scan my python code with Sonar (version 7.1) and pylint. I'm using plugin SonarPython (version 1.10) 
Command execute scan:

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=${PROJECT} -Dsonar.projectVersion=${VERSION} -Dsonar.projectName=${PROJECT} -Dsonar.python.pylint=/usr/bin/pylint -X
```

And my `sonar-project.properties` file:

```
sonar.projectBaseDir=./
sonar.sources=./
sonar.python.coverage.reportPath=./coverage.xml
sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin=cobertura
sonar.python.xunit.reportPath=./nosetests.xml
sonar.exclusions=test/**
```

I got :

> DEBUG: PylintSensor skipped because there is no related rule activated
>   in the quality profile 
>   DEBUG: PylintImportSensor skipped because
>   there is no related rule activated in the quality profile

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an absolute paht for the `sonar.projectBaseDir`?

Comment: It is `03:32:30.027 INFO: Base dir: /tmp/jenkins/workspace/${project-name}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It skips because I do not active Pylint rules on Sonar server. 
You can refer: [Here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/pylint-and-qualityprofile/5462/8)